# Is it possible to avoid multiple headers while using -getmerge function while saving to local directory in hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a python script which saves a spark dataframe as csv to HDFS.

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(filename, header='true', sep=',')
```

I then need to combine the part .csv files present in HDFS and then download them to a local location as a single .csv file. I am using -getmerge for this. The issue I'm facing now is that while combining the part files, the header is being appended multiple times which is unwanted. I want to get a single .csv file with just one header. Is it possible to do that?

```
subprocess.call("/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -getmerge " + filename + " " + single_csv, shell=True)
```

I cannot use .coalesce(1) while saving to HDFS because the file size is large and it causes Out of Memory expection.

Comment: have you tried below solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this-

### Load the data

```scala
 val df1 = spark.range(2).withColumn("name", lit("foo"))
    df1.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |0  |foo |
      * |1  |foo |
      * +---+----+
      */
```

### Save the data as csv without header

```scala
    df1.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv("/path/test62709439")

    /**
      * part-0...csv
      * -------------
      * 0,foo
      *
      * part-1...csv
      * -------------
      * 1,foo
      *
      */
```

### Save column names

```scala
    spark.sql(s"select ${df1.columns.map(s => s"'$s'").mkString(", ")}")
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .csv("/path/test62709439")

    /**
      * part...csv
      * -----------
      * id,name
      */
```

you can then merge